# Kubernetes load balancer external ip is not populating with ingress address

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I'm facing an issue with the address populated with load-balancer external-ip. Did i make any mistake writing yaml file? Beginner for AWS EKS, unable to find any help by older questions and online.

**Issue:** This svc (service) external-ip does not get populated with ing (ingress) address field.

Kubectl commands results:
[image: kubectl command results]

app.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: p-app-ezycards
  namespace: production
  labels:
    app: p-app-ezycards
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: p-app-ezycards
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: p-app-ezycards
    spec:
      tolerations:
      - key: eks.amazonaws.com/compute-type
        operator: Exists
        effect: NoSchedule
      - key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
        operator: Exists
        effect: NoExecute
        tolerationSeconds: 300
      - key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
        operator: Exists
        effect: NoExecute
        tolerationSeconds: 300
      containers:
      - name: p-app-ezycards
        image: 87376XXXX.XXX.XXXX.XXX:test
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
```

http-ingress file

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: p-ezycards-app
  namespace: production
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: p-app-ezycards
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
    - host: mmxxxx.xxxxxx.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: p-app-ezycards
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Thank you so much for your efforts to read this!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: ok @DavidMaze i removed images, Can you help with the specific question?

Comment: You say you're "facing an issue"; what's the specific problem you're encountering?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have highlighted issue with bold, As beginner i am not much aware what is the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are using alb as external IP, then configurations with nginx-controller don't make sense. (maybe I'm wrong here if you are using specific requirements)

If Specifically you wants to Go with nginx only, then you can check the logs of nginx-controller which resides inside kube-system.

But here the best practice should be go with alb-controller. it will reduce your workarounds.